# Write and test a function that accepts an array of strings and returns the longest word in the array

Tags: javascript

Example of what the function should output =>
maxWord(["The", "Albatross", "just", "ate", "your", "lunch"]) => "Albatross"

After looking at other examples of similar problems, I came up with this. But it says its an illegal return statement.

```js
function maxWord(string){
 var longestWord= arr[0];
 for(var i = 0; i < str.length;i++){
  word = arr[i];
  if(word.length > longestWord.length){
   longestWord = word;
  }

  }
 }
 return word;
}
```

Comment: You have a ***typo*** in that there's an extra closing brace. Take better care when indenting your code and/or use a linter and code formatter.

Comment: I'd suggest using `Array.prototype.reduce`.

Comment: `function maxWord(s) { return s.split(' ').reduce((a,b) => a.length < b.length ? b : a); }` simple =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's because you have an extra close brace and you have typos in the variables to use.

Change your code to be:

```
  function maxWord(arr){
    var longestWord= arr[0];
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length;i++){
        word = arr[i];
        if(word.length > longestWord.length){
            longestWord = word;
        }

    }
    return longestWord;
}
```

Here's a fiddle of it working https://jsfiddle.net/qjm4qxwy/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution in es6 using Array.reduce

```
const maxWord = (words) => {
   return words.reduce((longest, word) => {
     longest = word.length > longest.length ? word : longest;
     return longest;
   }, '')
}
```